# WordPress Permalink 404 Error after Subdomain to Root Migration

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, permalinks

I have a WordPress installation at Subdomain.
I wish to have the website display the blog at http://www.website.com

The WordPress folder is located at http://www.website.com/wordpress/

The migration is complete but the pretty permalinks do not work. For the default permalink structure, its fine but for `/%postname%/` it displays 404 Errors.

This is the .htaccess code WP has generated in the root

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I got the permalinks to work for Godaddy. I had to add an extra line in .htaccess to make this work.
GoDaddy appears to be taking 404 error page over .htaccess and thus was giving errors for all pretty permalink request.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

The **ErrorDocument 404 /index.php** line above makes all the difference with GoDaddy. It forces handling of 404 error with that of WordPress index page and works fine.

Hope this helps everyone trying to make pretty permalinks like `%postname%` work with Godaddy

Comment: Fixed it. My issue was with my Ubuntu server. This is how I fixed it: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnablingUseOfApacheHtaccessFiles

Comment: Over three years later and that's still a valid answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but there still exists 404 error using the above code. Any ideas? I am on GoDaddy.

Comment: The .htaccess file should not be in the root it should be under the /wordpress/ folder and should contain the above code. If that doesn't work please provide an example of a page not working and the permastructure.

Comment: I got it to work. It looks like GoDaddy gives precedence to the 404 error page over .htaccess. So, I added the following code `ErrorDocument 404 /index.php` It now works as expected. I am adding the new .htaccess as an answer. Thanks @pittishgunner for all your help

Answer (score 0):

I changed my permalink structure yesterday and verified that its 301 redirection. You can consider changing your .htaccess permission to 777 and then change to pretty permalink from default permalink. Once done, change back the permission of .htaccess to 777.
Here is a quick tutorial:
[How to change WordPress permalink without 404 error](http://wpfreesetup.com/86/how-to-change-wordpress-permalink-with-301-perma-redirection/)