# wordpress 500 internal sever error with htaccess and 404 not found for all pages except hompage after removing htaccess

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, internal-server-error

I returned my permalink structure to plain but it makes a new `.htaccess` file with same rules and causes **500 internal server error** 
in `httpd.conf`  AllowOverride  is set like the following line:

```
AllowOverride All
```

I read the old questions and from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7548799/5753091) added this line:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

to the first line of `.htaccess` file but problem not resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Try to go to **Settings** > **Permalinks** and click **Save changes** button **without** any changes on that page. This action will regenerate correct .htaccess file for your WordPress site.

If not work, you should check your PHP error log for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely this is an issue with **.htaccess** and the permalink setting. For setting premalink you can follow the above answer. 
But you may get the same errors, as your **.htaccess** may not be writable. 
So you need to make the **.htacces** file writable so when you reset the permalink, WordPress can able to write the **rewrite rules** to **.htaccess** file. 
**Just for your information :** to change the permalink **Go to Settings -> Permalinks -> Postname ** and save the new settings.

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: the problem is that WordPress  writes rewrite rules to .htaccess file when i click on permalinks. and when i delete rewrite rules works.